# Sqlalchemy dynamic creation of children

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

It is necessary to create a model of children
with different methods. I decided to do a meta
class:

```
class AProxy(object):
    #some methods

class BProxy(object):
    #some methods

class TestMeta(_BoundDeclarativeMeta):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        base = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
    if not dct.get('__tablename__'): # child create
        return base 
    prefix = name
    tablename_prefix = base.__tablename__
    children = ['A', AProxy,
                'B', BProxy]
    module = sys.modules.get(base.__module__)
    for child in children:
        n = prefix + child[0]
        b = (child[1], base)
        d = dict(__mapper_args__= dict(polymorphic_identity= tablename_prefix + child[0].lower()))
        setattr(module, n, TestMeta(n, b, d))
    return base


class Test(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    __metaclass__ = TestMeta
    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        return {'polymorphic_identity': '%s' % cls.__tablename__,
                'polymorphic_on': cls._type,
                'with_polymorphic': '*'}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key= True)
    _type = db.Column(db.String(30), index= False)        
    # some columns
```

An error duplication of the index column '_type'. If you remove the index database is created fine, but when you create a child (TestA, TestB) field '_type' None is cleared. If you manually set the '_type' when fetching an error: 
    AssertionError: No such polymorphic_identity u'testa' is defined

Comment: the metaclass approach here looks unnecessary as you can use abstract bases/mixins to do this.  but it's not clear what specific schema structure you're looking to create here.  Do AProxy and BProxy have their own tables?

Comment: AProxy and BProxy of a table, they just have a
different set of methods. The problem was
solved using the __ init__ instead of __ new__.
I know that the use of meta-classes is not a
good practice, but there are ~ 15 Proxy classes
and are used in several places. And it is an
attempt to reduce the code.